# Is $\min ( tF_1 (x) + (1-t) F_2(x) , G(y)) \leq t \min ( F_1(x), G(y)) + (1-t) \min ( F_2(x), G(y))$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, convex-analysis

Let $F_1, F_2,G$ be cumulative distribution functions on $\mathbb R$ (so bounded by $0$ and $1$, increasing, $0$ in $-\infty$ and $1$ in $\infty$).

Is it true that

$$\min ( tF_1 (x) + (1-t) F_2(x) , G(y)) \leq t \min ( F_1(x), G(y)) + (1-t) \min ( F_2(x), G(y)) $$

for all $t\in[0,1], x \in \mathbb R,y\in \mathbb R$ ? I tried to find a counter-example without success and I have no idea how to prove such a statement. Any ideas? I still doubt that it is correct.

Comment: For real $a$, is the function $x\mapsto \min(x,a)$ concave?

Comment: @kimchilover are you saying that the inequality is actually reversed?

Comment: I guess I am, and that Jensen's inequality gives a simple proof.